# I cant get my ipad 1 to pop up in the organizer with the button saying "Use device for development"

Tags: xcode

I'm having a problem getting my ipad 1 to pop up in the organizer with the button saying "Use device for development"  My iphone 5 worked due to running the latest iOS but nothing Ive tried yet works for the ipad 1. In the organizer my ipad one pops up, the indicator light is green but I have no button saying, "Use ipad for development" I put the interface builder versioning as iOS 5.1 and development as the previous version "Xcode 4.2" saved it, but still got nothing. I still cant get the organizer window to give me the button to use device for development.

Answer (score 1):

Green light? Are you sure you aren't using this device for development already?

Anyway, quick Google search gave me this:

> If the device was used for development in the past, the “Use for Development” button may not appear. If this happens, click “Add to Portal” at the bottom of the screen instead.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html

Comment: Ya I've added, subtracted, and added again.  it still wont show up in the ios devices with the simulators.

Comment: I haven't used it for development yet.

Comment: AWWWW!  EURIKA!!! I found out whats up, thanks for the help.  I had the deployment on the storyboard set to 5.1 but in the main (initial) project window theres another option for deployment target that I needed to put to 5.1.